# Proper way of handling char * returning data in swig/python

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have a C++ routine MyClass::myFunction(char * message). which returns a message by writing in the message buffer. This routine is exported to python via SWIG. When the routine is called, I assume that the char * points to a python allocated memory area associated to the string.

Now, the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn25) says that modifying the contents of this buffer is a baaad idea, which makes sense because strings are supposed to be immutable. So the question now is: what is the proper way of dealing with this case?

Comment: If you want to *return* a string, then do that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't have control on that function, nor I can wrap it. It would screw up too many things now.

Comment: What do you have control over?

Comment: assuming `message` is (or can be made to be) a unique parameter name then you can create a typemap that will handle it as an out parameter. But that means changing the `.i` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [cstring.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn12) library:

> The cstring.i library file provides a collection of macros for dealing
>   with functions that either mutate string arguments or which try to
>   output string data through their arguments.

Particularly the `%cstring_mutable` macro:

```
%include <cstring.i>
%cstring_mutable(char *ustr);
...
void make_upper(char *ustr);
```

In Python:

```
>>> make_upper("hello world")
'HELLO WORLD'
```

The parameter name matters. In this case any function with a `char *ustr` parameter will be affected. So either make your parameter name unique or make all your mutable string parameters have the same name.

Note that there's also an `expansion` option that might be useful in your case.

Comment: Since strings are immutable it can't change the argument in-place. So in Python this turns into a return value. There's an example and more documentation in the `cstring_mutable` section of the link I provided.